# Web Reference Service Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, service

I am trying to add a web reference service in an ASP.net MVC project.
However when I add the service I got following error,

> Custom tool error: Unable to import WebService/Schema. The object
>   'Settings' already contains a property
>   'FreeLance_Web_VATService_checkVatService' not of type
>   WebServiceUrl.    C:\FINALBUILD\User Portal\User.Web\Web
>   References\VATService\Reference.map

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some How the designer.settings.cs had already a service referenced with the same. Once I changed the name of the service and added again, it started working.

Comment: Quite basic, but still relevant in 2022. Thanks this fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all of the above and I still experienced this issue.  It turns out that a reference was stored in my app.config.  I got rid of it and then re-added the web refences. That fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is remove the existing services and try to re-add the reference to the mvc application.
Other thing is try to search with the **'FreeLance_Web_VATService_checkVatService'** name in the settings.cs and see what it has. 
There should not be same name for the objects which will lead to this conflict

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as I had copied the configuration from another file. I had to delete the configuration and update the web reference. When you add web reference settings is automatically added to the configuration file and hence you should not copy that part from another file. Remove  and  from your configuration file,update web reference and check if it is recreated.